# Console.WriteLine() and the need for so many argument overloads?

Tags: c#

I was browsing through the documentation and noticed that `Console.WriteLine()` method had several overloads.  Particularly, my curiosity and partial confusion pertains to these:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg);
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0);
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1);
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2);
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);
```

It seems redundant. What is the need of the other four overloads on top of the first one?  The first method is able to do everything that the other methods can do.  Is there a performance concern that they were trying to tackle by providing additional overloads, which handle up to four arguments (last one)?  Is the overhead of going through an array of up to four arguments large enough to provide the need for these overloads?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In general you are correct that the first overload can suffice for the other overloads.  This is not strictly true though because the `params` keyword can't be used for indirect cases like method group binding.  For example

```
delegate void E(string format, object o1);
E e = Console.WriteLine;
```

The `params` overload won't satisfy this case, it will only work when this particular overload is present

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0);
```

That's a pretty esoteric case though.  The more important reasons are the following

1. Not every CLI language is required to support the `params` keyword.  Having the overloads reduces the burden on those languages by removing the need to manually create an array for a simple WriteLine` call
2. Performance.  Calling the `params` overload forces the caller to allocate an array, even if it's done implicitly by the compiler.  Allocations are cheap in .Net but not free.  Little things like this add up quickly especially on commonly called methods like `Console.WriteLine`.  Having the other overloads allows for the common cases to avoid this allocation

Comment: I had thought about the method group case in my answer but I'm pretty sure method group conversion wasn't introduced until C# 2.0 whereas the WriteLine overloads date back to at least 1.1.

Comment: @jaket The convenient syntax was added in C# 2.0. But the same point applies if you use the explicit `new E(Console.WriteLine)` in C# 1.

Comment: Is array allocation even noticeable with how slow a Console.WriteLine is?

Comment: @insta it's not the speed but the accumulation of allocations which are the problem. GC is cheap not free and in complicated apps GC is often the dominating performance factor. Stopping common sources of needless allocation is important for performance

Answer (score 38):

The overloads are for the convenience of C++/CLI programs where the params keyword doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a great answer, to a great question, IMHO, too.

Comment: Ahh... that actually makes a lot of sense.  Shame on me, C++ was my first language. :)

Comment: the basics starts from the first language, clever answer buddy

Answer (score 4):

I think all of you guys are forgetting that params was introduced in C# 2.0. Therefore, the overloads also exist from .NET 1.1, when the params keyword did not.

Comment: jaket mentioned that.

Comment: Read his comment on JaredPar's answer.  That is one of the reasons why he didn't include the param explanation in his answer.

Comment: @Noobacode, it's true that he did but it's inferred (as how I read it). I give an upvote (for as little as that is worth) to Alan here because he stated it in a more direct manor.

Comment: From this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) params keyword exist in .Net 1.1 also

Answer (score 1):

I think the question asked has already the good and explanatory answers by [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242474/console-writeline-and-the-need-for-so-many-argument-overloads/22242841#22242841) and [jaket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242474/console-writeline-and-the-need-for-so-many-argument-overloads/22242718#22242718) but one point what I think can be relevant too,

**I think the ease of use and freedom for the users** to use any of the above functions according to there requirement, there way, there need is much more convenient rather then imposing them to create an array, when they really do not require it.

I think too of the old days when I began to learn the C#  **I hardly used arrays** and to use arrays was a complicated task for me, to assign it and then initialize them with proper values was really complicated and time consuming too...

Comment: But the idea of `params` is so you can either pass an array, or explicitly write all the arguments. a method like `void do(params object[])` can be either called with `do(new object[] {"some", "stuff"}` or `do("some", "stuff")`. I don't think your point is exactly applicable here.

Comment: @Kroltan but can you tell how many beginners do really know the meaning of `params` and they know if `params` is there then you can pass the variables as comma separated.

Comment: @Kroltan I too was not knowing the use of `params` could be like this for a long time and in help section displayed in Visual Studion if I get `array []` as argument I will think the same to supply array as argument....

Answer (score -3):

This is not really for the performance issue as such. However, increasing the usability is a valid reason behind it.

The code below, would give you a small insight.

```
public class TipCalculator {
    private const double tipRate = 0.18;
    public static int Main(string[] args) {
        double billTotal;
        if (args.Length == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("usage: TIPCALC total");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            try {
                billTotal = Double.Parse(args[0]);
            }
            catch(FormatException) {
                Console.WriteLine("usage: TIPCALC total");
                return 1;
            }
            double tip = billTotal * tipRate;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bill total:\t{0,8:c}", billTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Tip total/rate:\t{0,8:c} ({1:p1})", tip, tipRate);
            Console.WriteLine(("").PadRight(24, '-'));
            Console.WriteLine("Grand total:\t{0,8:c}", billTotal + tip);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly refer to the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa324774(v=vs.71).aspx
for more information.

Comment: How does that increase usability?  The first method can do exactly the  same thing as the other four.  You're referring me to documentation, while I just said that I was looking through documentation.  I know what that method is used for and how to use (I'm not new to C# by any means).  But why is there a need of additional overloads on top of the first one.

Comment: I think what he means is, for only passing one parameter, there is no point in creating an array to hold it, and passing it to the method - why not just pass the one parameter? That would be my reason for doing something like that

Comment: @SCassidy1986: **You** don't make the array when it's a params method, unless you want to. The compiler will make one automatically. That's the point of both params and this question.